# How to copy objects between two S3 buckets using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I've to copy S3 objects (text and media files) from one S3 bucket into another. Although bucket names are different, both buckets allow access using the same credentials. How can I achieve that using Nodejs?

I've so far been able to get a list of objects. For some reason it just gives me the list of first 100 objects and show that `900 more items` are available. Here is what I've so far:

### index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let s3 = new AWS.S3({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    region: process.env.REGION
});

const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
console.log(BUCKET);

var params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET, 
};

const obj = s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
})
```

I've two questions:

1. How can I copy S3 objects between S3 buckets? Do I need to use a combination of `getObject() and putObject()` or `copyObjects()`?
2. Why the listObject() only gives me 100 objects with a mention of 900 more items. The total number of S3 objects is a lot more than these numbers combined. How can I get all the objects in the bucket?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`copyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) to move an object between buckets. Just make sure you pass `CopySource` as the object you want to copy, and `Bucket` as the target bucket.

To answer your second question: `listObjectsV2` is a paginated SDK function. If you want to list more than the max (defaults to 1,000) objects, you'll have to iteratively call `listObjectsV2` with the `StartAfter` option set to the last key of the previous request, which will start listing objects after that key. Keep calling this, updating `StartAfter`, until some number of objects is returned less than 1,000.